# Sum elements with the same index in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df:

           nace_r2   2017   2018  
NUTS_ID

AT          G-I      5300   2800
AT1         G-I      2200   1900
AT2         G-I      2100    900
AT            J      3900   1500
AT1           J      2000    700   
AT2           J      1900    800
...
```

I would like to add all the elements that have the same index (NUTS_ID) and put them in a new dataframe:

```
df2:

           2017    2018
NUTS_ID

AT         9200    4300
AT1        4200    2600
AT2        4000    1700
...
```

Please note that I have some NaN in my original dataset and I can't simply discard the rows. How could I do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `I can't simply discard the rows.` Is possible see it in data, what you mean?

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for your answer, it seems to do what I need. I meant that doing something like dropping rows that only contain NaN would mean a future problem, as I need to keep all the rows even if they contain zeroes or NaN after adding them. Your solution keeps all the rows, so everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you can sum by index values, not numeric columns are discarded:

```
df = df.sum(level=0)
print (df)
         2017  2018
NUTS_ID            
AT       9200  4300
AT1      4200  2600
AT2      4000  1700
```